# MongoDB Aggregation: $Project (how to use a field on the other field of the same projection pipeline)

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, projection

This is what i want my aggregation pipeline to look, i just don't know how to properly do it

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
{
   $project: {
      all_bills: ‘$all_count’,
      settled_bills: { $size: ’$settled’ },
      overdue_bills: { $size: ‘$overdue’ },
      settled_percentage: { $divide: [‘$settled_bills’, ‘$overdue_bills’] }
   }
}
])
```

I want to use the "settled_bills" and "overdue_bills" fields inside the "**settled_percentage**" field on same projection pipeline. How to?

Comment: Please show us your collection schema, so that we can know how to help you achieve what you want. What is all_count, settled, overdue and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i guess there is no way I can use fields on other fields that co-exist on same projection pipeline.

(assume the settled_bills and overdue_bills consist not just the 'size' but with long query operators )

I'll just do this instead, so i will not repeat the code on the $divide.

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
{
   $project: {
      all_bills: ‘$all_count’,
      settled_bills: { $size: ’$settled’ },
      overdue_bills: { $size: ‘$overdue’ },
   },
   $project: {
      settled_percentage: {
          $divide : ['$settled_bills','$overdue_bills']   
       }
   }
}
])
```

Answer (score 3):

From what i can see, i think you want `$let`.

You can create local variable which can be used inside the `$let` expression.

**Try this:**

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
{
   $project: {
      all_bills: ‘$all_count’,
      settled_bills: { $size: ’$settled’ },
      overdue_bills: { $size: ‘$overdue’ },
      settled_percentage: { 
          $let : {
              vars : {
                  local_settled_bills : { $size : "$settled"},
                  local_overdue_bills : { $size : "$overdue"}
              },
              in : {
                  $divide : ["$$local_settled_bills","$$local_overdue_bills"] 
              }
          }
       }
   }
}
])
```

Here, you create local varialbes in `vars` expression, which can be used inside(and only inside `in` expression). I have created `local_settles_bills`, and `local_overdue_bills`, and which can be used in `in` expression with `$$` as prefix.

I hope this helps you out.

Read [MongoDb $let documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/#exp._S_let) for detailed information on $let.

**Alternatively, you can do this as well :**

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
{
   $project: {
      all_bills: ‘$all_count’,
      settled_bills: { $size: ’$settled’ },
      overdue_bills: { $size: ‘$overdue’ },
      settled_percentage: {
                  $divide : [{"$size" : "$settled_bills"},{"$size":"$overdue_bills"}]   
       }
   }
}
])
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, yep i was thinking of doing that too or just straight to $divide: [{ $size : "$settled"}, {$size : $overdue}], but i want something shorter, the reason why I ask.

Comment: because the fields settled_bills: { $size: ’$settled’ }, overdue_bills: { $size: ‘$overdue’ }, are just a simple example but in reality, in my code it is a long query :)

Comment: Yes i thought to give you that solution as well, but then i thought you might not know about this approach, so gave you a new approach to acheive it. Anyways that solution works exactly as fine :)